# React router dom Prompt doesn't trigger while navigating from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I just want, whenever I try to navigate away from Component A, to be warned first. My code below doesn't work. I can navigate between A and B without seeing any Prompt.

Component A:

```js
import {Prompt} from 'react-router-dom';
class ComponentA extends Component {

     render()
        {
            return (
                <>
                  <h1>Component A</h1>
                    <Prompt
                    when={true}
                    message='Are you want to leave ?'
                    />
                </>
            );
        }
    }
```

Component B

```js
    class ComponentB extends Component {
     render()
        {
            return (
               <h1>Component B</h1>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you seeing any error in the dev console?

Comment: no error in the dev console while navigating